# c# gridview not showing result of stored procedure sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, gridview

I am trying to populate the gridview with a stored procedure with the following code but whats happening is the gridview is not showing anything.

```
SqlConnection myConnectiona = new SqlConnection("user id=HOME-PC\\HOME;" +
                               "password=password;server=HOME-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;" +
                               "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                               "database=tabrem; " +
                               "connection timeout=30");

        SqlCommand pro = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[doctor]", myConnectiona);

        pro.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(pro);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();



    try
    {
                myConnectiona.Open();

      da.Fill(dt);
      dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;


    }
    catch (Exception w)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (myConnectiona.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            myConnectiona.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Is it maybe that you are missing the `Databind()` command?

Comment: C# is too broad, so is gridview. Looks like you are using `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView`, please update the question tag to avoid "use `DataBind`" comments/posts.

Comment: Now on the subject. Did you check that `dt.Rows.Count > 0` and `dt.Columns.Count > 0`? Also `dataGridView1.AutoPopulateColumns` is `true`?

Answer (score 1):

After you set your datasource:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

Edit:

In that case, you need to use BindingSource:

```
bindingSource.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: this is not asp it is c# so databind not needed.

Comment: is dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the datatable to the gridview as shown below:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.Databind();
```